# Proving an equality in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Now, I want to show that

$$ A \cup B = A \cap B \leftrightarrow A = B $$

I  tried to show that every element from the left side is in the right and vice versa.

I started by showing $$ A = B \rightarrow A \cup B = A \cap B $$

Now assuming $$ A = B $$ to be true and plugging in the definition 
$$ \forall x : (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B ) \wedge ( x \in B \rightarrow x \in A ) $$

and rearranging, I could quickly show that $$ x \in (A \cap B) \rightarrow x \in (A \cup B) $$ 
Now I need to show that $$ x \in (A \cup B) \rightarrow x \in (A \cap B) $$ to show the equality  ($A \cup B = A \cap B$)  and I struggle to do that.

Furthermore I struggle with the other direction, that is to prove $$ A \cup B = A \cap B \rightarrow A = B $$

Here, too, I could use the definition giving me 
$$ (x\in A \lor x \in B ) \rightarrow (x\in A \wedge x \in B ) \wedge (x\in A \wedge x \in B ) \rightarrow (x\in A \lor x \in B ) $$ 
but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any hints on how to go from here are appreciated.

Comment: I would like the downvoter to explain why the downvote. The question is explained with working and tags.

Comment: I am reminded of the far side cartoon "stimulus response? Don't you ever think?".  If $A = B$ then $A \cup B = A \cup A = A$ and $A \cap B = A\cap A = A$.  *sheesh*.

Comment: Everybody but you seems to understand that this question is not about understanding the equality but about how to formulate a real proof. Everybody can see this equality in a Venn Diagram. Proving it is a different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose 
$$A\cup B=A\cap B$$
Now assume $\exists a\in A:a\not\in B$. This implies $a\in A\cup B$ and $a\not\in A\cap B$ or equivalentely $A\cup B\neq A\cap B$, which is a contradiction. Hence $\forall a\in A: a\in B$ and because of symmetry we have also proven that $\forall b\in B:b\in A$. Now, we easily see that $A=B$

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to do the first direction: show that both $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$ are equal to something else, rather than showing them to be equal to each other. In fact, I don't see a way to proceed from your end-point, other than to do the "easier way".

The other direction: suppose $A \not = B$. Then there is an element $a$ in $A$ which is not in $B$ (wlog, since if it were the case that every element of $A$ were also in $B$, then $A$ is a strict subset of $B$ so there is an element in $B$ but not in $A$). What can we say about $a$ in $A \cup B$ and $A \cap B$?

Comment: I believe Mastrem typed out what you had in mind in your second paragraph. Your suggestion does make that problem a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

$A=B$ does indeed mean that $(a\in A \implies a \in B) \land (a\in B \implies a \in B)$ but I can not think of a more complex, confusing, and convoluted way to express this.  If $A = B$ they are the same  set.

If $A= B$ then $A\cup B = A\cup A=A$ and $A \cap B = A \cap A=A$.

$A\cup A= A=A\cap A$ because $a \in A \iff (a\in A \lor a\in A) \iff a\in A \land a\in A)$.

But even if I did it your convoluted way.

Let $a \in A \cap B$ then $a \in A \land a\in B \implies a\in A \lor a \in B \implies a \in A\cup B \implies A\cap B \subset A \cup B$.  This is *always* true, even if $A \ne B$.

Let $a \in A \cup B$ and $A= B$.  By your definition of equality, $a \in A \lor a \in B$  if $a \in A$ then $a \in B$.  If $a \in B$ then $a \in B$.  So either way $a \in B$. And so $a \in B \implies a \in A$ so $ a \in A$.  So $a \in B$ and $ a \in A$ so $a \in A\cap B$.

So $A \cup B \subset A \cap B$.  So $A\cup B = A\cap B$.

But that was preposterously and unnecessarily complicated as $A$ **IS** $B$ we didn't need to do make any distinction between them.

So that's the first half.

The easy obvious and *trivial* half.  If $A = B$ then $A\cup B = A\cup A = A = A \cap A = A \cap B$.

*sheesh*.

==

No the hard direction.  Let $A \cup B = A \cap B$

Let $a \in A$ then $a \in A \lor a \in B$.  So $a \in A \cup B$.  (Note $A \subset A \cup B$.  That is *always* true.)  So as $A \cup B = A \cap B$, $a \in A \cap B$.  So $a \in A \land a \in B$.  So $a \in B$ so $A \subset B$.

Let's not be so absurdly obtuse in proving $B \subset A$...

Let $a \in B$.  Then $a \in B \subset A\cup B = A\cap B$.  Therefore $a \in A$.

So $B \subset A$.  So $A = B$.

So $A=B \iff A\cup B = A\cap B$.

=====

But we could have done the whole thing, a *lot* easierly.

$A = B \implies A\cup B = A\cup A = A = A\cap A = A\cap B$.

$A\cup B = A\cap B \implies A \subset A\cup B = A\cap B \subset B$ and $B \subset A \cup B = A\cap B \subset A$.  So $A =B$.

Comment: I like your style!

Answer (score 1):

$x\in A\implies x\in A∪B\implies x\in A∩B\implies x\in B$

Same as opposite

Comment: Think again on your implication stating that $x\in (A\cup B)\to x\in (A\cap B)$?  If $x\in A$ then certainly $x\in A\cup B$.  But if $x \in A \setminus B,$ we do not **have** $x \in A\cap B$.  The upvote here makes me think someone is simply checking off a list of answers, because **this answer is wrong.**

Comment: That is, suppose $x\in A,$ and also $x\in (A\setminus B)$.  Of course, then $x \in (A\cup B)$.  However, $x \in A \land  \lnot (x \in B )$, Hence, if $x \in A\setminus B$, then $x \notin (A\cap B) = \varnothing.$

Comment: @amWhy A∪B = A∩B so x∈(A∪B)→x∈(A∩B)